# Dropzone Hidden Field Working Intermittently

Tags: dropzone.js

I have a basic dropzone form:

```
<form action="/library/annual-equipment-requests/upload-files" class="dropzone">
<input name="record" type="hidden" value="Value">
<div class="fallback">
<input name="file" type="file" multiple="">
</div>
</form>
```

This works sometimes and not others. When it does work, I can see the post data in the network developer tools result:

**Request Payload**

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryI7wN7T1SFcHzGC2t
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="record"

Value
------WebKitFormBoundaryI7wN7T1SFcHzGC2t
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Lighthouse.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

And when it doesn't work....

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryI7wN7T1SFcHzGC2t
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Lighthouse.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Any ideas?